# My SQL database specific scenario?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a project to develop for property dealer
he has entry in db of all plots in an area
plots are of different sizes and assigned numbers like 1,2,3,4...
plots status are (sold/not sold)
he want to query to list any number of consecutive plots where status='no sold' and sum(plots_size) between some value
suppose a customer needs many consecutive plots of total size = 800 sq feet.
I have tried like this

tbl_polts(plotID, size,..., status)
tbl_plot_neighours(plotID, neighour_PoltID)

please help in database structure and query.

Comment: very unclear, but my answer should help...good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.plotID, a.size, a...., a.status, b.neighbour_PlotID, SUM(a.plots_area)
from tbl_plots as a
inner join tbl_plot_neighbours  as b
ON a.plotID = b.plotID
WHERE a.status = 'no sold' and SUM(plots_area) between '1' and '4';
```